# How to dynamically extend a class in java?

Tags: java, oop, generics, wildcard

I'm trying to dynamically extend an object based upon the native type of the parameter I pass to its constructor.
I've read through some java generics and wildcard stuff, but I can't seem to find a good approach.

Pseudo Code for explanation:

```
public class myClass extends <?> {
    // Constructor
    public myClass(<?> param) {
    }
}
```

Will I have to use some kind of builder class? If so, how would I lay this out?

**Edit:**
I had a feeling my approach was pretty bad, hence my asking here. To further explain:

I have an interface with many sub-interfaces, some of which also have sub-interfaces. For my purposes, I can't edit the super-interface to add methods since it's an API. I have an event which passes me one of the sub-interfaces, which I want to be able to cast to my own object that has more methods and properties, but I still want access to the methods of the sub-interface.

For example, the sub-interface is called entity. I could do `myClass extendedEntity = new myClass(entity)`, which has the new methods I want to expose. If I made the passed sub-interface a property of the object, I could do `extendedEntity.entity.originalMethod()` to access method contained in the sub-interface. But I want to have it as `extendedEntity.originalMethod()` as well as `extendedEntity.addedMethod()`.

Does this make sense to anyone, and is there something obvious I could do that I'm missing?
(Educated as a mechanical engineer, the java is a hobby so forgive me!)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java extend generically specified type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119460/java-extend-generically-specified-type)

Comment: There's a whole barrel of wrong here.  There's a good reason you can't do something like this.  Seriously consider using interfaces and reflection instead.  Tell us what you want to accomplish, and I'd be willing to bet we could do it in a better way.

Comment: Your approach isn't the best, but:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011443/extending-or-adding-new-classes-at-runtime-in-java

Comment: When you end up needing to do stuff like this, you most often made some grave error in your design earlier. Go back and re-evaluate whatever design-decision prompted this need and examine it from an OO-design perspective.

Comment: Yes, I only need to do this because I'm trying to extend API and expose it in the nicest way possible. Added further explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of worrying about generics, why not investigate the Delegate pattern? Your extendedEntity can implement `Entity`, store the passed-in `entity` in a private field, and delegate all `Entity` method calls to it. It can have whatever extra methods you desire on its own interface.

I'm not sure if you quite understand how casting works either. It doesn't magically turn one object into another. The cast `A a = (A) b` only works if `b` is *already* of type `A` (or a subtype).

Comment: I realise casting doesn't work that way, haha- I just meant in an ideal world, that's what my goal is. Probably a bad use of terminology, sorry.
Also, if I `myClass implements Entity`, won't I not have access to sub-interfaces of `Entity`? That's my problem

Comment: But you can implement multiple interfaces.

Comment: I have 40 interfaces! The top-level interface is Entity, and then it's like a Tree of sub-interfaces.

Comment: You should definitely investigate using the Delegate pattern. It's ideal for cases when the number of subclasses explodes like that. You essentially replace compile-time type definition with run-time type definition.

Answer (score 1):

Generics is not for extending the class. Is for specifying that a class deals with a given class (or set of classes). For example `List<String>` is a `List` that stores `String`, instead of `Object`.

And generics ARE ONLY USED AT COMPILE TIME. Even if what you are asking for was supported, at runtime it would end as

```
  public class myClass extends Object {
    public myClass(Object param) {
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Compiling code at run time seems reasonable to solve this problem. Also once upon a time I heard [BCEL](http://commons.apache.org/bcel/index.html), you can look at it too.